# Apache Drill 1.6.0 failure in starting embedded Drillbit (windows)

Tags: windows, apache-drill

I am unable to start Embedded drillbit on windows machine and getting the following error. I have checked for the jars in 3rd party folder where Jackson-databind-2.7.1.jar is present, still it's saying class not found exception. Can you help me here?

> Error: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.
>
> [Error Id: 4e654256-f63d-434f-8f41-981892a776b5 ] (state=,code=0)
>   java.sql.SQLException: Failure in starting embedded Drillbit: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.
>
> [Error Id: 4e654256-f63d-434f-8f41-981892a776b5 ]
>           at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.(DrillConnectionImpl.java:120)
>           at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillJdbc41Factory.newDrillConnection(DrillJdbc41Factory.java:64)
>           at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillFactory.newConnection(DrillFactory.java:69)
>           at net.hydromatic.avatica.UnregisteredDriver.connect(UnregisteredDriver.java:126)
>           at org.apache.drill.jdbc.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
>           at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.connect(DatabaseConnection.java:167)
>           at sqlline.DatabaseConnection.getConnection(DatabaseConnection.java:213)
>           at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1083)
>           at sqlline.Commands.connect(Commands.java:1015)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>           at sqlline.ReflectiveCommandHandler.execute(ReflectiveCommandHandler.java:36)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:742)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.initArgs(SqlLine.java:528)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:596)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:375)
>           at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:268)
>   Caused by: org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException: UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION ERROR: Failure while attempting to load instance of the class of type org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistry requested at path drill.exec.storage.registry.
>
> [Error Id: 4e654256-f63d-434f-8f41-981892a776b5 ]
>           at org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserException$Builder.build(UserException.java:543)
>           at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.getInstance(DrillConfig.java:88)
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.server.DrillbitContext.(DrillbitContext.java:85)
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.work.WorkManager.start(WorkManager.java:105)
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.server.Drillbit.run(Drillbit.java:110)
>           at org.apache.drill.jdbc.impl.DrillConnectionImpl.(DrillConnectionImpl.java:118)
>           ... 18 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>           at org.apache.drill.common.config.DrillConfig.getInstance(DrillConfig.java:86)
>           ... 22 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readerFor(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader;
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.serialization.JacksonSerializer.(JacksonSerializer.java:32)
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.store.sys.PersistentStoreConfig.newJacksonBuilder(PersistentStoreConfig.java:81)
>           at org.apache.drill.exec.store.StoragePluginRegistryImpl.(StoragePluginRegistryImpl.java:90)
>           ... 27 more
>   apache drill 1.6.0
>   "this isn't your grandfather's sql"

Comment: Its working perfectly fine on a linux machine but I am running in to problems just with a windows machine.

Answer (score 5):

The issue is related with the HADOOP_HOME environment variable
If it is set, Embedded Drill does not start properly
My HADOOP_HOME was set because I use sometimes Spark or Hadoop MapReduce on my machine.

So, with
set HADOOP_HOME=
and then
sqlline.bat -u "jdbc:drill:zk=local"

The initialization is completed and the Drillbit starts